# Translucent JPopupMenu inside a Translucent Window - alternative?

Tags: java, swing, awt, translucency

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to safely allow popups to be translucent even when the parent container is also translucent?

If not, **what would be wise alternative to use or extend instead of `JPopupMenu`?**

Note: *Translucent* refers to a component not 'having a background', similar to the effect of `setOpaque(false);`. Thanks.

[image]

From a forum answer by user *camickr* in 2009:

> I don't know if transparency painting has changed in 1.6.0_10. Prior
>   to that I believe transparency can only be achieved in lightweight
>   components (ie. Swing does all the painting). JFrame, JWindow and
>   JDialog are not lightweight because they use OS components.
>
> In the case of a popup, it is lightweight when entirely contained
>   within its parent frame. But a lightweight popup can not be painted
>   outside the bounds of the frame so a JWindow (I believe) is used as
>   the popup, which can't be transparent.

**SSCCE:** Showing translucent  JWindow over the top of translucent JFrame

```
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class OpaqueWindowSSCCE {

    private int countdown = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OpaqueWindowSSCCE();
    }

    public OpaqueWindowSSCCE() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("OpaqueWindowSSCCE");
        final JWindow window = new JWindow();

        new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(--countdown == 0){
                    frame.dispose();
                    window.dispose();
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            }

        }).start();

        frame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics paramGraphics) {
                super.paintComponent(paramGraphics);
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) paramGraphics.create();
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g.setColor(new Color(50, 50, 50));
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 10, 10);
                g.setColor(new Color(180, 180, 180));
                g.drawString("Closing in " + countdown + " seconds", 20, 25);
            }
        });

        window.setContentPane(new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics paramGraphics) {
                super.paintComponent(paramGraphics);
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) paramGraphics.create();
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g.setColor(new Color(180, 180, 180));
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 10, 10);
            }
        });

        frame.setUndecorated(true);

        ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane()).setOpaque(false);
        ((JComponent) window.getContentPane()).setOpaque(false);

        AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, false);
        AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(window, false);

        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        frame.setBounds(200,200,500,500);
        window.setBounds(600,600,200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this can be achieved, in the given context, that you are doing, with `JWindow` using this funciton [setOpacity()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setOpacity(float)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code part, I had used `JWindow` though

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WindowExample
{
    private JWindow window;
    private JLabel updateLabel;
    private int count = 5;
    private Timer timer;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            updateLabel.setText("Closing Window in " + count + " seconds...");
            count--;
            if (count == 0)
            {
                timer.stop();
                window.setVisible(false);
                window.dispose();
            }   
        }
    };

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setOpacity(0.5f);
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
            {
                x = me.getX();
                y = me.getY();
                window = new JWindow();
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                JLabel positionLabel = new JLabel(
                    "X : " + me.getX() + " Y : " + me.getY());
                updateLabel = new JLabel("TImer");  
                contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
                contentPane.add(updateLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                contentPane.add(positionLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
                window.setContentPane(contentPane);
                window.setOpacity(0.5f);
                window.setSize(200, 100);
                window.setLocation(x + window.getWidth(), y + window.getHeight());
                window.setVisible(true);
                count = 5;
                timer = new Timer(1000, timerAction);
                timer.start();
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new WindowExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the output :

[image: TRANSLUCENT]

**WARNING I AM GETTING**

```
C:\Mine\JAVA\J2SE>javac -d classes src\OpaqueWindowSSCCE.java
src\OpaqueWindowSSCCE.java:1: warning: AWTUtilities is internal proprietary API and may be removed i
n a future release
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
                  ^
src\OpaqueWindowSSCCE.java:68: warning: AWTUtilities is internal proprietary API and may be removed
in a future release
        AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, false);
        ^
src\OpaqueWindowSSCCE.java:69: warning: AWTUtilities is internal proprietary API and may be removed
in a future release
        AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(window, false);
        ^
3 warnings
```

Comment: Thanks for the SSCCE! It's clear that `JWindow` is capable of displaying properly - the drawback is that I'll have to implement the showing and hiding to imitate that of a `JPopupMenu`, which wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: You are MOST WELCOME AND KEEP SMILING :-), yeah that's true, even in `JPopUpMenu` I guess you have to click at some other place to hide the previous :-), Just the advantage of `JWindow` is that we can add whatever we want to add to it, to show it to the user :-)

Comment: Yeah, but `JPopUpMenu` handles focus very nicely and will have to make sure it works well. For some reason I didn't think of `JWindow` at all... thanks, I'll give it a shot and come back to you. :D

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work though, because setting arbitrary `OPACITY` isn't the issue here. What I would like is for the popup to not have a background at all (so that round corners can be round). The key thing to note is that the `JFrame` is not opaque, via `AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, false);`

Comment: @paranoid-android : Sorry for the late reply, some server issues came in. May you please provide some small working code that I can try my hands on, if it's not a big issue, it would be great :-)

Comment: @paranoid-android : Thankyou for this, MAY I ask you a simple question, as to why this warning coming to me, do check my answer for that. I am glad though, that my answer did helped you somewhere :-) WOWO, I learned something from your inputs too, how to paint rounded `JWindow` , that's impressive :-)