# How to Show Only plain Message in Java without any Ok or Cancel Option?

Tags: java, swing, message, jdialog, jwindow

I want to show some Message at run time in my app without giving any option in Message Dialog Java swing , and my app also run with this showing message. So how can I do that?

Comment: Why? Surely that will just block the user from continuing?

Comment: Please have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10528086/1057230). I hope this can be used in this case too , though without opacity related stuff :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like pop-up notifications that don't affect the program flow?

If so, the following might be useful:

- http://jcarrierpigeon.sourceforge.net/