# set tooltip text at a particular location

Tags: java, swing, jtooltip

I have my output window as shown [here](http://codes-at-igit.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/2/7/12272842/output.jpg)
My complete code is:
http://codes-at-igit.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/2/7/12272842/travellingsalesmanproblem.java
The circles are different G.P.S locations. I want to show the location i.e. , the longitude and latitude when mouse hovers on a node. I tried set tool tip text but it doesn't give privilege to specify the locations at which the text should occur. I have coded it in swing Java . I am working in Netbeans 7.1.2. So how can I do this? 
**How do I set tool tip text at a particular position?**

Comment: Could you provide the portion of you code concerned? It'd be easier

Comment: its a very long code I am calculating the optimal travel route on a set of nodes using two method's brute force and simulated annealing and them plotting the result.does this help you? or you need the code.

Comment: You could use `JLabel`. So when the mouse passes over a node, it'll write the location to the `JLabel` and clear it when the mouse exists

Comment: can you please elaborate.or can you give me some link or tutorial.?about how to set tool tip text at a specific location.

Comment: may be this link will help. It's **How to use** for tool tips.[how to use tool tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)

Comment: @JosephElcid I have read this but it does not give me any provision of manually setting the location which I want in my application.

Comment: If I'm correct, in your code the locations are stored in 2 `arrays`. So you can simply read the corresponding value from those array and convert them to `String`. Or I'm not understand your problem...

Comment: yes I can convert them to string but these nodes / locations are not any J component in which I can directly set tool tip text but these are locations I want to show the locations only when mouse hover on the respective node.That's why I cant use this directly.

Comment: @user1503567 : Here is one related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10528086/1057230), where you can use `JWindow` to show the info at a specified location.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. Why not reduce this to something that succinctly explains the problem?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply override `public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event)` of the underlying JComponent. Then based on the location of the event you can return null or the tooltip related to the node.

Here is a small snippet demonstrating this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.beans.Transient;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;

public class TestTooltip {

    private static class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
        private Ellipse2D circle1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 20, 20);
        private Ellipse2D circle2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(300, 200, 20, 20);
        private Ellipse2D circle3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(200, 100, 20, 20);

        public CirclePanel() {
            // Register the component on the tooltip manager
            // So that #getToolTipText(MouseEvent) gets invoked when the mouse
            // hovers the component
            ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // Simple paint of 3 circles on the component
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.fill(circle1);
            g2.fill(circle2);
            g2.fill(circle3);
        };

        /**
        * This method is called automatically when the mouse is over the component.
        * Based on the location of the event, we detect if we are over one of 
        * the circles. If so, we display some information relative to that circle
        * If the mouse is not over any circle we return the tooltip of the 
        * component.
        */
        @Override
        public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
            Point p = new Point(event.getX(), event.getY());
            String t = tooltipForCircle(p, circle1);
            if (t != null) {
                return t;
            }
            t = tooltipForCircle(p, circle2);
            if (t != null) {
                return t;
            }
            t = tooltipForCircle(p, circle3);
            if (t != null) {
                return t;
            }
            return super.getToolTipText(event);
        }

        @Override
        @Transient
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            // Some size we would like to have
            return new Dimension(350, 350);
        }

        protected String tooltipForCircle(Point p, Ellipse2D circle) {
            // Test to check if the point  is inside circle
            if (circle.contains(p)) {
                // p is inside the circle, we return some information 
                // relative to that circle.
                return "Circle: (" + circle.getX() + " " + circle.getY() + ")";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test tooltip");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new CirclePanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTooltip().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: @user1503567 I added some comments in the code. Basically, you override `getToolTipText(MouseEvent event)`. In that method you test if you are over one of the location you would like to return a tooltip. If yes return the appropriate tooltip. The method will be automatically called when mouse hovers your component (don't forget to register your component on the tooltipmanager)

Answer (score 4):

Try over-riding getToolTipLocation(), for example:

```
JButton buttonAbove = new JButton("Above") {
      public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent e) {
        return new Point(20, -30);
      }
    };
```

from here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ToolTipLocationExample.htm