# Remove the title bar from JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Is there any way to remove the title bar from `JOptionPane`?

I need to create an option pane without option title bar.

Comment: Consider[JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) :-) [Related example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10528086/1057230)

Comment: Easiest way would be to set the title as "".

Comment: Could you please explain? G. L. Blanc

Comment: Have you tried undecorated jdialog extracted from the joptionpane?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: that won't make the title-bar dissapear...

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use a JOptionPane?

You can use a J(Internal)Frame or a splashscreen without window-decoration, too!

```
JInternalFrame inFrame = new JInternalFrame();  
BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane =  
      (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) inFrame.getUI()).  
      getNorthPane();  
inFrame.remove(titlePane);
```

Comment: Yes I used JOptionPane as well as I tried for internal jFrame but it'z quite complicated

Comment: what do you mean "complicated"? :D the posted code should do the trick, doesn't it?

Comment: with a little customizing it should be able to serve... ;)

Comment: Thanks desperateCoder. will try.

Comment: +1, I liked this new approach, never touched `JInternalFrame` before. Though this vote will come in 9 hours from my side, my limit is gone for now :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw: Thank you! There are a lot of ways to get, what you want, if you are very, very desperate :D This one is very useful for e.g. search-windows in tables, lists, etc. ;)